# Can I access the parameters of multiple objects created with object constructor function?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I'm new with js and I'm trying to understand if it's possible to access the parameters of ALL the objects created with an object constructor function. For example:
I have an object constructor function:

```js
function objectconstructor (width){
    this.color=width;
    this.element = document.createElement('div')
    element.style.backgoundColor = this.width + 'px';
}
// Now I have two objects created with the objectconstructor:
var object1 = new objectconstructor (100)
var object2 = new objectconstructor (200)

// Now I have the following function 
function () {
    if((object1.width>100) || (object2.width>100)){
        alert('hi')
    }
}
```

I would to shorten the if statement, something like:

```js
if (All_objects_created_with_object_constructor_function.width > 100) {
  alert('hi')
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that without your own code that maintains a list of initialization values.

Comment: As the values of the properties can be changed later, can you elaborate that you want to check the current values, or the initial values (`width` arguments)? Also, the code you have, and the code you want are not equal. The condition in the current code passes when `width` of at least one object is greter than 100, the goal says all the objects should have the width greater than 100. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a collection of them in an array, and then use `some` to check if any (or "some") of the entries in the array match the condition:

```
if (theArray.some(({width}) => width > 100)) {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

But you'd need that array. The constructor function could create it, but that would typically not be ideal; better to have the code calling the function add to the array.

Live Example:

```js
function Thingy(width) {
    this.width = width;
//       ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−− `this.width`, not `this.color`
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.style.backgoundColor = this.width + 'px';
//  ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−− Added missing `this.` here
}

// Create Thingys
const thingies = [
    new Thingy(50), // 50 instead of 100 just to show we're not just checking the first one later
    new Thingy(200),
];

if (thingies.some(({width}) => width > 100)) {
    console.log("At least one Thingy matches");
} else {
    console.log("No Thingys match");
}
```